# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerabl[],

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

Here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<_24By7CallAndBPOPvtLtd.Models.Job_DetailModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Current Jobs</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Job Title</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        ....
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.job_title)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)</td>
            ....
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="detail" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.Job_ID })'"  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".JobDetailModel">Detail</button>
           </td>
       </tr>
    }  
</table>
<div class="modal fade JobDetailModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/MainDashboard/_Details.cshtml")           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is My Controller:-

```
public ActionResult Index(Job_DetailModel jvm)
{
    db.Job_Det.ToList();
    return View(jvm);
}
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    Job_Det jobdetail = db.Job_Det.Find(id);
    if (jobdetail == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(jobdetail);
}
```

Here is My ViewModel:-

```
public class Job_Detail Model
{
    public int Job_ID { get; set; }
    public string job_title { get; set; }
    public string min_education { get; set; }
    public string job_description { get; set; }
    public string Responsibilities { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Job_Shift { get; set; }
    public string Job_Type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Positions { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
    public string Career_Level { get; set; }
    public string Experience { get; set; }
    public int Deptt_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Posted_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Apply_Before { get; set; }
    public string posting_timestamp { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Gender_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

I want detail of a job using popup, but i got the following error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '_24By7CallAndBPOPvtLtd.Models.Job_DetailModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[_24By7CallAndBPOPvtLtd.Models.Job_Deta‌​ilModel]'.

Please tell me how to call partial view as i am using view Model.

Comment: What line is the error thrown on?

Comment: i dont know..its give the error below... System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '_24By7CallAndBPOPvtLtd.Models.Job_DetailModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[_24By7CallAndBPOPvtLtd.Models.Job_DetailModel]'.

Answer (score 1):

You Index action doesn't make any sense. Should it be... ?

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
        var jobs = db.Job_Det.ToList();
        return View(jobs);
 }
```

Comment: I know this but if u go down and see the partialview i am calling, this is the main problem, i m getting..

Comment: it gives the same error as before..

Answer (score 0):

You are using @model IEnumerable<> in Your view which indicates that the model expected by the View is of type IEnumerable.
To avoid this error pass model to view like so :

`@model _24By7CallAndBPOPvtLtd.Models.Job_DetailModel`

or pass a IEnumerable of _24By7CallAndBPOPvtLtd.Models.Job_DetailModel as model to the view in controller .

Comment: i already tried this..i m calling partialview in the same view for popup window..